# Using JSON to convert an array from C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs

I have been struggling with consuming c# code converted to the javascript angular navigation tree structure. The code is correctly converted because when I hard code the returned json value my app works. However, when I try to set a variable equal to the returned get value the app does not work. Is there some kind of conversion I am missing between the get command and entering it into my treeContents?

```
$scope.deviceNavCollection = DeviceSvc.DeviceNavCollection.get({ deviceId:$scope.currentDeviceID });
var treeData = $scope.deviceNavCollection;
$scope.treeContents = treeData.data;
```

The format of the data (which matches abn-tree)

```
{"data":[{"label":"Connection","id":1,"src":"../Device_Common/partials/Connection.html","children":null},............}]}]}
```

HTML

```
<abn-tree tree-data="treeContents" on-select="onTreeItemSelected(branch)" select-id="treeSelectId" icon-leaf="icon-file" expand-level="1"></abn-tree>
```

c#

```
string strJSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(navCollection);
return json;
System.Console.WriteLine("C#: Leaving GetDeviceNavCollection method");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The request is asynchronous, you have to wait until it's finished otherwise it will be undefined:

```
DeviceSvc.DeviceNavCollection.get({ deviceId:$scope.currentDeviceID }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.deviceNavCollection = response;
    var treeData = $scope.deviceNavCollection;
    $scope.treeContents = treeData.data;
});
```

This is, of course, assuming your `DeviceNavCollection` service is returning a promise.

Comment: It's like the data is not getting through to the variable I don't understand. I know it's getting something because I write something to console in my c#. I posted it in the question for reference.